# Multi-Conditional torch.where replace with constant value

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to use a series of conditional statements with torch.where and replace those selected values with an ID 1-10
`torch.where((2dtensor[:,1] < 4.2) & (2dtensor[:,1] > 3.8) & (2dtensor[:,0] < 3.6), 2dtensor, 1)`.

I know that torch.where wants: `torch.where(condtionals,x,y)` where `x` and `y` are the same shape, but I'm looking to make `y` a 10 long tensor filled with ID's.  I have tried giving it that ten long tensor and also just giving the value `1` for `y` as seen above and havent gotten much to work.

Any help or suggestions greatly appriciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: remember to supply a minimal reproducible example, a piece of code that can be run stand-alone and shows your problem clearly, together with current output (even if it is an error, post it in full) and desired output.